# simple wiki and reference tracking

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, wiki, mediawiki, has-and-belongs-to-many

I'm trying to wrap my head around designing a simple Wiki style app.  In a traditional wiki, say wikipedia, are 'links' referenced in any kind of backend/complex way?  Ie HABTM... or are links simply links?

I'm trying to decide myself what to do, a bit different but similar.  I have pages written by individuals which they can attribute to themselves or credit a.. say a famous author.  Should I save this attribution as merely a tag?  The tag would create a reference to the famous person, which may or may not exist, but could also be created, but nothing more than a link.  OR, do I dive deep and create a real data relationship (HABTM) ?

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

A SQL-style Has And Belongs To Many mapping table is never necessary in Mongo.

If you'd like to provide, for example, a "what links here" view for a page, then I would do something like this for each page in your Wiki. I'll give an example of a page about pandas:

```
{
    _id: "Panda",
    text: "Page's contents go here",
    links: ["Raccoon", "Weasel"]
}
```

You're using the page's title as its _id. To find titles of pages that link to "Raccoon", you can query like:

```
db.pages.find({"links": "Raccoon"})
```

Obviously, you should make an index on "links".